# Parsing / Coverting date in PHP

Tags: php

How do you parse a date in a format like this:

```
Wen, 22-Jul-2010 12:33:10 +0200
```

to RFC_922 format or another like `Y-m-d H:i:s`?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Some slight confusion may eventuate with the fact that 22/7/2012 is a Sunday - `strtotime` will interpret the date as 28/7/2012 in an effort to match the "Wed" ("Wen" gets you unix epoch :-).

Comment: Thank you, Wen>>Wed - it was mistake when typing

Comment: Actually it should be a Thursday, unless you intended an incorrect day (looked at 2012 instead of 2010)

Answer (score 3):

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('Wed, 22-Jul-2010 12:33:10 +0200') );`

One liner, note that it doesn't work directly with the date provided becuase you wrote "Wen" instead of "Wed", but I assume you wouldn't receive a date that would be wrong in that manner.
 If you do, then call `str_replace` like so: `$yourDate = str_replace('Wen', 'Wed', $yourDate);` before passing the date to strtotime.

Comment: `strtotime()` also has the bonus that it actually calls a standard libc library call, so it's really a lot more powerful than many people realise.

Comment: Thank you, Wen>>Wed - it was mistake when typing

Comment: In that case, then this is your solution (:

Answer (score 0):

`date_parse()` also could be a good choice

Comment: This might be suitable for other use cases, but this one can be solved more easily.